# Kotlin Channels to send events between fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have 2 **opened**  fragments and I want to send an event with data type `String` from one fragment to the other. Is there a good way to do it? I also found [this](https://gist.github.com/takahirom/f2dbcc3053adfd87ac7e321d95a23021) but I'm not sure if it's right, but it's the only one around.

So practically I want to make a simple EventBus with Kotlin channels.

Comment: That implementation is basically correct, although that implementation allows you to request an ReceiveChannel<T> where T is any type that you specify... so you don't really need that if you are just using strings.

Comment: honestly it's just a single Event for the whole app :P. currently I'm using a shared viewmodel but I wanted to stay in the kotlin world